# Problems with auto start counter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have problems with this code.
when i open the page it starts counting automatically, its the same when i refresh the page
i want to make it just to start counting only when i click the button . not starting its self
i dont want it to be auto start counter

thanks for the help

```js
setTimeout (function(){
    document.getElementById('timer').disabled = null;
},10000);

var countdownNum = 10;
incTimer();

function incTimer(){
setTimeout (function(){
  if(countdownNum != 0){
      countdownNum--;
      document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
      incTimer();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Done';
    }
  },1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="timer" />
  <p id="showtime">Start</p>
 </form>
```

Comment: Just replace `incTimer()` with a line that adds that function as an event handler. No I won't write it for you, this counts as basic research. If you tried and couldn't figure it out, please share your attempt and how it went wrong.

Comment: Wrap your code into a function. And point onClick handler for your button to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, with a `mousedown` [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener):

```js
// Removed so it won't trigger after 10 seconds. Added downward
//setTimeout (function(){
   // document.getElementById('timer').disabled = null;
// },10000);

var countdownNum = 10;

// Function won't trigger immediatly
// incTimer();

// Add an event listener on dom element with id «showtime»
showtime.addEventListener("mousedown", incTimer, false);

function incTimer(){
setTimeout (function(){
  if(countdownNum != 0){
      countdownNum--;
      document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
      incTimer();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Done';
        // Added here
        document.getElementById('timer').disabled = null;
    }
  },1000);
}
```

```css
#showtime {cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="timer" />
  <p id="showtime">Start</p>
 </form>
```

[List of possible events for listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Answer (score 0):

So the autostart here is because you're actually calling your `incTimer()` on line 7 of your code. There are a few things to be aware of here too.

First, put your javascript below your html, so when the js runs, the html elements are already in the dom. This way you don't need that timer at the top to remove the disabled attribute.

Next, you're using the "submit" type on your input, which is fine, but when a form "submits" it will cause the page to reload unless you prevent this with `event.preventDefault()`.

Finally, better to use the `setInterval` here instead of the `setTimeout` so you can use that to update your `countdownNum`.

Here is a working refactored version of your code. I also added a reset button here too. Notice on the button I used `type="button"`, this is because without that, some browsers will treat any button inside a form as `type="submit"` by default, causing the unnecessary reload just like the input.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    #reset:disabled {
      display: none;
    }

    #reset {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <form id="timer" disaabled="true">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" />
    <p id="showtime">Start</p>
    <button type="button" disabled id='reset'>reset</button>
  </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    const form = document.getElementById('timer');
    const submitInput = document.getElementById('submit-button');
    const resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');

    let timer;
    let countdownNum = 10;

    form.addEventListener('submit', incTimer);
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetCountdown);

    function resetCountdown() {
      countdownNum = 10;
      submitInput.removeAttribute('disabled')
      resetButton.setAttribute('disabled', true)
    }

    function incTimer(event) {
      event.preventDefault()

      timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (countdownNum != 0) {
          countdownNum--;
          submitInput.setAttribute('disabled', true)
          document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
        } else {
          resetButton.removeAttribute('disabled')
          document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Done';

          clearInterval(timer)
        }

        console.debug('interval')
      }, 1000);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks @chris this is what i need, but can you remove reset button and let submit button reset itself to normal from disabled

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are starting the timer by yourself automatically, to make it run only on button click, you need to assign a click event to the button.

This code should do the trick.

```js
setTimeout (function(){
document.getElementById('timer').disabled = null;
},10000);

var countdownNum = 10;
//incTimer(); <--- This line was starting it automatically,  you don't need it.

function incTimer(){
setTimeout (function(){
    if(countdownNum != 0){
    countdownNum--;
    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Please wait ' + countdownNum + ' seconds';
    incTimer();
    } else {
    document.getElementById('showtime').innerHTML = 'Done';
    }
},1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="timer" />
  <p id="showtime" onclick="incTimer()">Start</p>
</form>
```

Comment: this is not even showing counting progress like mine, tho its what i need, but now the problem its not showing counting progress after clicking button

Comment: please run it there and see, its still not showing counter progress

Comment: now this looks not working on all browsers, coz not working on chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 and latest firefox

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 83.0.4103.116 here.

Comment: i got to stick on my old version, seems this not working

Comment: Worst issue is the button get enabled after 10 seconds anyway.